# Layout issue on emulator

Tags: android, button, android-tablelayout

I try to order some buttons in a 4x2 matrix in my android app. In eclipse, it looks perfect:

[image]

My problem is, that on my device / in the emulator all buttons are nearly on top of each other:

[image]

On the second screenshot you see only one button because the others are set to unvisible. When I push the button a different button is shown on nearly the same place like the one before.

Here´s my layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>


    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/willi"
            android:text="Button" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

It's the first time that I user `TableLayout` so I don´t understand why that happens.

Comment: Here's a guess: `drawable/willi` is too big for the layout dimensions you're giving.  On the device, the driver works out something reasonable. In the emulator's driver, it gives up and assigns zero.  Try bigger button dimensions.

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately still the same issue. It's interessting that even the buttons in row2 are on the same place like the ones from row1.

Comment: Does nobody an idea about that issue?